# How to return a list of errors from a Spring controller that currently returns an incompatible class?

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have a POST method that returns type ResponseEntity where ProgramDetails is structured like:

```
ProgramDetails {
    Program program;
    ProgramInfo programInfo;
}
```

On a successful save this controller returns ProgramDetails. However, when there is an error I would like to return a list of errors:

```
ApiError {
    List<String> errors;
}
```

To have the flexibility to send either I have created an interface ProgramDetailsResponse and have made ProgramDetails and ApiError interfaced with ProgramDetailsResponse.

Is there a better way to implement this or is it considered bad practice to use an interface this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this one of two ways.

The first way is that I would just return a wildcard ResponseEntity from the controller, then you can return either ResponseEntity of ProgramDetails or ApiError, like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething() {
   if (no_error) {
     return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(programDetails));
   else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ApiError());
   }
}
```

The cleaner approach is to use ControllerAdvice and throw the exception from your controller method.

Your controller would look like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<ProgramDetails> doSomething() {
   if (no_error) {
     return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(programDetails));
   else {
      throw new ApiException();
   }
}
```

This would be an advice class to handle this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler
  public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleGlobalException(ApiException e) {
     return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ApiError(e.getMessage()));

  }
}
```

This advice method will fire anytime one of your controllers throws ApiException, but you can configure it for any exception or exceptions you want to catch.  From there, the advice handles the response entirely and will return the ResponseEntity with your wrapped error class.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using exceptions for control logic.  Your suggestion works, but it would drive me crazy to have to find the advice to figure out what happened.  I think aspects are overused.

Comment: @duffymo when in Rome :)  ControllerAdvice is the mechanism that Spring provides for MVC exception handling, and if you're using spring-web, you're already using it whether you know it or not.  I prefer this route because it places all the exception logic in one place and it's very easy to see exactly where the error originated from.

Comment: I usually handle all the exceptions in the controller using try/catch/finally.  No exceptions leave my controllers.  I love Spring and Spring Boot.  I'm sure they know more about design and implementation than I do.  But that wouldn't be my choice.

Comment: I like to have fewer code paths, and once you know how spring's magic works, it's super easy to maintain.

Comment: I believe the case you're describing, though, is resolved with the first portion of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider creating a common wrapper class to encapsulate both normal and error responses, allowing the response structure to stay consistent, regardless of success or failure, like:

```java
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private T data;
    private List<String> errors;

    public ApiResponse(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ApiResponse(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So you would always get a response with either a data field or an errors field (or potentially both, if you desire), and the HTTP status code would still indicate the success or failure of the request.